# Regular expression for matching dynamic part in url while mocking API is not working

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to mock an API which has some dynamic part, so I tried to use a regular expression but it is not working.

URL is: https://example.com/programs/2fcce6e3-07ec-49a9-9146-fb84fb0105cf/subprogram/0f8ddca8-cf5a-4174-bc75-0928f71a0e87/metrics?activeOnly=false

The Id's after programs and subprograms are dynamic.

I tried to mock API by using a regular expression as below but it did not work.

```
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo('https://example.com/programs/.*/subprogram/.*/metrics?activeOnly=false', { method: 'GET' })
    .respond(mockObject, 200, {
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
    });
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you pass a string, not a regular expression. Instead, pass a real and correct regular expression.

See also: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thanks...I passed in as .```onRequestTo(/https:\/\/example.com\/treaty-programs\/programs\/.*\/subprogram\/.*\/metrics\?activeOnly=false/)``` and it worked